# Is GwtQuery (gQuery)a cross browser library like jQuery?

Tags: gwt, gwtquery

Does GwtQuery offer the same browser compatibility as jQuery? If not, what browsers has it been tested with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- gQuery(GwtQuery) supports Browser compatibility as jQuery.
- Each browser gets separately compiled JS

gQuery is an entire rewrite of GWT in jQuery.

GQuery and jQuery are built around selectors.

Both support CSS standard selectors plus extra selectors (:text :password :hidden etc).

jQuery uses the sizzle engine. A javascript engine which works with any browser and has optimizations per browser.

GQuery has optimized engines written in java.

The more appropriate engine is selected in compile time.

GQuery uses a modified sizzle version for IE6/7

GQuery adds compile-time optimizations when using compiled selectors.

**Compiled Selectors**

- Use them with immutable selectors and when selector performance is a goal in your application.

**Selectors Performance**

- GQuery in compiled mode produces the faster javascript code to select DOM elements.
- GQuery dynamic selectors are, in most cases, faster or equal than any other library.

**Events**

- GQuery provides methods for assigning event in a cross-browser way.
- GQuery event system is compatible with Gwt.
- issues: – When Gwt detaches a widget, events added via GQuery are lost.

**References:**

https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/GettingStarted
http://vinaytechs.blogspot.in/2009/09/gwtquery-jquery-in-gwt.html